# How to render Django model field in template form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to add [django-faicon](https://github.com/dantium/django-faicon) field in a form inside my template.

I have a form like:

```
from faicon.fields import FAIconField

class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    icon = FAIconField()
```

And I add the field into template:

```
{{ form.icon }}
```

But instead a real icon field I see on webpage:

```
<faicon.fields.FAIconField>
```

What is a proper way to render icon field outside Django admin?

Comment: try form.icon.url

Comment: @vpdiongzon not works, this field should render link to modal window as it works in admin